# Rebuild page every x seconds, not on data change flutter. How to Approach this?

Tags: flutter, firebase, logic

This is more of a question regarding a general structuring approach as appose to code-specific problems but regardless I'm totally stumped.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

In very simple terms, I'm trying to make an app where people are able to join groups and compete. Each user is given a Hp that is adjusted every x seconds depending on if they are are are not doing something. If they are doing something, their hp rises, if they are not their hp falls. While their state is in the "doing" their hp rises consistently by 1 every x seconds, and falls by 1 when "not doing".

Where I am getting stuck is how to make the other clients being able to display each member's hp bar rising and falling as they change between the two states using firebase.

**My approach so far has been:**

having two arrays in firebase, one for each state. When a user clicks to change to "not doing" or "doing" they go from one list to the other. All clients are listening for changes in these two arrays, when they detect changes, local logic figures out who moved and then updates that user's hp direction (+1 or -1). Then when the local timer is called every x second hp is incremented by that amount.

**The problem is:**

That I have no idea how to structure this or even if this is the most efficient method of doing it. Especially with the local timer portion that updates each user's hp locally, feel like having this for each user is going to cause so many bugs.

I really just need some help trying to figure out how to get started on solving this in a clean, logical manner. I'm pretty new to programming and would love some guidance and suggestions on solving this requirement.

Comment: Be specific about your problem, I couldn't it completely. You might have a look into Stream builders and using ```stream.periodic``` as stream function

Comment: that seems like It could work, my only concern would be the number of reads that would be getting processed. Having each client read the database every x seconds sounds like it would get pretty expensive no? That's why I was trying to figure a solution with only reading on user state changes.